# How tf.train.shuffle_batch works?

Tags: tensorflow

Does it do one shuffling in one epoch, or else?

What is the difference of tf.train.shuffle_batch and tf.train.batch?

Could someone explain it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because have not even tried to read documentation

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First take a look at the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch ). Internally batch is build around a FIFOQueue and shuffle_batch is build around a RandomShuffleQueue.

Consider the following toy example, it puts 1 to 100 in a constant which gets fed through tf.train.shuffle_batch and tf.train.batch and later on this prints the results.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(1, 100 + 1)
data_input = tf.constant(data)

batch_shuffle = tf.train.shuffle_batch([data_input], enqueue_many=True, batch_size=10, capacity=100, min_after_dequeue=10, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
batch_no_shuffle = tf.train.batch([data_input], enqueue_many=True, batch_size=10, capacity=100, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for i in range(10):
        print(i, sess.run([batch_shuffle, batch_no_shuffle]))
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Which yields:

```
0 [array([23, 48, 15, 46, 78, 89, 18, 37, 88,  4]), array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])]
1 [array([80, 10,  5, 76, 50, 53,  1, 72, 67, 14]), array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])]
2 [array([11, 85, 56, 21, 86, 12,  9,  7, 24,  1]), array([21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30])]
3 [array([ 8, 79, 90, 81, 71,  2, 20, 63, 73, 26]), array([31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40])]
4 [array([84, 82, 33,  6, 39,  6, 25, 19, 19, 34]), array([41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50])]
5 [array([27, 41, 21, 37, 60, 16, 12, 16, 24, 57]), array([51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60])]
6 [array([69, 40, 52, 55, 29, 15, 45,  4,  7, 42]), array([61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70])]
7 [array([61, 30, 53, 95, 22, 33, 10, 34, 41, 13]), array([71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80])]
8 [array([45, 52, 57, 35, 70, 51,  8, 94, 68, 47]), array([81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90])]
9 [array([35, 28, 83, 65, 80, 84, 71, 72, 26, 77]), array([ 91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100])]
```

Comment: Note, as you mentioned the read the docs, it is now listed as deprecated and suggests using `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle(min_after_dequeue).batch(batch_size)` now.

Answer (score -1):

tf.train.shuffle_batch() shuffles every epoch.

Comment: Please be explicit. For instance, does it shuffle the contents inside each batch without changing? Does it shuffle all the items amongst the batches? Does it shuffle the order of the batches?