# How to use tf.train.shuffle_batch to train NN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow

I've trained my neural built with tensorflow network and got some overfit I'd like to reduce. I hoped learning the model on batches could help ad I tried to test this idea. I found tf.train.shuffle_batch() and fought this may do the thing. So I tried and it didn't work. Tensorflow's documentation doesn't help. I've found [one topic, but the example there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203872/how-tf-train-shuffle-batch-works) only prints arrays out. It was promising to use it to learn NN but in my case istead of getting data divided to n-element batches I got them multiplied n-times in additional dimension.

Here is the code sample:

```
nnInput = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_width], "network_input")
nnOutput = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_width], "expected_labels")

batch_readings, batch_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [
        tf.constant(train_readings), 
        tf.constant(train_labels)
    ],
    batch_size = 15,
    num_threads = 4,
    capacity = 500,
    min_after_dequeue = 250,
    allow_smaller_final_batch = True
)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for epoch in range(learning_steps):
    print("epoch:", epoch)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    print("Input data shapes:", train_readings.shape, train_labels.shape)
    for batch in range(10):
        x, y = sess.run([batch_readings, batch_labels])
        print("Batch shapes:", x.shape, y.shape)
        sess.run(train, feed_dict = {nnInput : x, nnOutput : y})
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

and here is the output:

```
epoch: 0 
Input data shapes: (165, 60) (165, 1) 
Batch shapes: (15, 165, 60) (15, 165, 1)
```

And the error list concludes with:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (15, 165, 60) for Tensor 'network_input_1:0', which has shape '(?, 60)'
```

The conlusion is not surprising when I fed the NN with 3D array but why do I get such a batch when I expect x:(15, 60) and y:(15, 1)? Why do I get x:(15, 165, 60) y:(15, 165, 1) and how to get useful batches?

I'm using tensorflow-gpu but hope this should work as well, right?

Comment: What is surprising here? `train_readings.shape` is `(165, 60)`, not `(60,)`. With the `batch_size = 15`, the function generates `(15, 165, 60)` tensors. Same for labels.

Comment: When I want to divide input data to batches I expect random subsets of input data. So having 165 cases of 60 element vectors I expect, let's say, 11 batches having 15 vectors each. Then, dividing input. Multiplying input is surprising. I don't understand this. Examples I've seen were giving i.e. 10 vectors 10 numbers each from a vector having 100 numbers. Result I have is much different, the code doesn't work and I don't know what can I do with it. The example data was `data = np.arange(1, 100 + 1)` so its shape was (1, 101)  and the result was 10 vectors with 10 numbers each. Not (10,1 ,101).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when using *tf.train.shuffle_batch*. The solution is to add the parameter **enqueue_many = True**.  The default is the parameter enqueue_many is **False**.

As explained in the documentation in [tf.train.shuffle_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch) 
"If enqueue_many is True, tensors is assumed to represent a batch of examples, where the first dimension is indexed by example, and all members of tensors should have the same size in the first dimension. If an input tensor has shape [*, x, y, z], the output will have shape [batch_size, x, y, z]."